# Automatic line break in ggtitle

Tags: r, ggplot2, line-breaks, ggtitle

Is there a way to force an *automatic* line break in the `ggtitle` command?

As part of a shiny application I use different plots with an input variable for the title.
Unfortunately, some of these variable values are too long to be displayed.

I came across one possibility by inserting `\n` (or a line break) manually in advance (Details here: [Improve editing of multiline title in ggplot that uses \n and extends far to the right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28023679/improve-editing-of-multiline-title-in-ggplot-that-uses-n-and-extends-far-to-the)). There, something like `ggtitle(paste("", title, "", sep = "\n"))` would be suggested.

Since including `\n` would be error prone as well as not flexible for different plot sizes I´m looking for another possibility.

Here is an minimal working example (adapted from lawyeR question linked above):

```
DF <- data.frame(x = rnorm(400))
title_example <- "This is a very long title describing the plot in its details. The title should be fitted to a graph, which is itself not restricted by its size."
plot <- ggplot(DF, aes(x = x)) + geom_histogram() +
  ggtitle(title_example)
```

You can find a image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MMKF.jpg

Do you have an idea how to e.g. adapt the `sep =`  operator to break lines automatically or are there maybe packages/ workarounds? Thanks!

Comment: Is this an option? https://stackoverflow.com/q/33484458/36061

Comment: Thanks @masher for noticing this related question! Since it´s rather a workaround I´ll use the package `ggtext` as suggested by @teunbrand which works great!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `ggtext` package's text elements could help solve this. `element_textbox_simple()` automatically wraps the text inside. Try resizing the graphics device window, it adapts!

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

DF <- data.frame(x = rnorm(400))
title_example <- "This is a very long title describing the plot in its details. The title should be fitted to a graph, which is itself not restricted by its size."

ggplot(DF, aes(x = x)) + geom_histogram() +
  ggtitle(title_example) +
  theme(plot.title = element_textbox_simple())
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfect for me, thanks @teunbrand!
If someone is wondering how to center your title `plot.title = element_textbox_simple(halign = 0.5)` does the trick

Comment: Is there also a way to make this work with subtitles? When I use a subtitle with ggtitle, the main title overlaps the subtitle.

Comment: I do not know a good solution to that issue.

Comment: @xyz just use `theme(plot.subtitle = element_textbox_simple())`